# RecyclerView takes time loading Adapter values in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I have a Fragment (HealFragment) with RecyclerView which it's adapter is a different class retrieving data from Firestore thanks to FirestoreRecyclerAdapter and it's working good. But whenever I switch to this HealFragment it stutters(slows down) a little bit trying to *set the adapter to the RecyclerView*. This happens because I set the adapter of the RecyclerView in the *onStart()* method.

> So my question is, how do I avoid this stuttering when the Fragment is loading the Firestore data with the Adapter class?

or

> How can I open the Fragment without stutters just with a ProgressBar and let the app get the Adapter data at it's own pace?

I have thought about implementing AsyncTask to the HealFragment class but heard that Firestore it's already asynchronous.

My temporary solution as you might see in the onStart() method of the HealFragment class is adding a 0.5 second delay(Handler) before attaching the Adapter to the RecyclerView. But I'd appreciate a more complete approach to this.

**Context:**

- HealFragment

```
    public class HealFragment extends Fragment {
      private View mView;
      private ProgressBar heFrProgressBar;
      private RecyclerView heFrRecyclerView;

      private HealAdapter healAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_heal, container, false);

        initializeViews();

        return mView;
    }

    //<--- Method to initialize and assign the views | Called in: onCreateView() --->
    private void initializeViews() {

        //Loading Firestore Data Process
        final String mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Query query = db.collection("User").document(currentUser).collection("Heals").orderBy("healColor");
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<NewHeal>()
                .setQuery(query, NewHeal.class)
                .build();

        healAdapter = new HealAdapter(options);
        heFrRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        heFrRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        heFrRecyclerView.setAdapter(healAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //** Actions to do after 0.5 second **
                healAdapter.startListening();
                heFrProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        healAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

- HealAdapter

```
public class HealAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<NewHeal, HealAdapter.HealHolder> {

    public HealAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<NewHeal> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HealHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final NewHeal model) {
        holder.setTaskTitle(model.getTaskTitle());
        //**Several setters like the one above**

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HealHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_heal, parent, false);
        return new HealHolder(v);
    }

    class HealHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //**Declaring Variables**

        HealHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.mView = itemView;

            //**initializingViews + settingOnClickListeners + loadingSomeMethods**
        }

        private void setTaskTitle(String xTitle) {
            singleHealTitleText.setText(xTitle);
        }

        //**Several setter methods more like the one above(setTaskTitle)**
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of AsyncTask, is deprecated and as you said Firebase is Asynchronous.

What you should do is make an interface to notify you when the fetching process is being made and then show a `progressBar` until you have your data to display.

you can attach a listener to the query to know when it finishes, and show a `progressBar` before fetching the data.

You can attach a listener to your query object and once the data is fetched you can hide a `progressBar`

```
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
         // data has been fetched, hide progress and update adapter data
          heFrProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         // set the new data to the adapter
         healAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});





@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
       healAdapter.startListening();
    }
```

You don't need to use a Handler with a delay, that is considered a bad practice, what you need to do is attach a listener to your asynchronous query, once the data has been fetched you need to hide the `progressBar`, update your data in your adapter and notify that the data has changed

Comment: The "CompleteListener" actually makes a lot of sense, not sure how I forgot about it. But when I implemented the same code you provided (with QuerySnapshot instead of DocumentSnapshot)  the ProgressBar is visible for less than a millisecond. Then the data still takes time to appear in the screen and the fragment transition still stutters unless I add few milliseconds of delay with Handler.